# return '-' dash if value doesn't exist in two tables in mySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new with databases and stuck with this situation.

My databases data updates from another URL. The local database is updated once per week, so I can't be sure when the data changes or does all of the data exist in all of the tables.

That's why I need to compare Spec_Names and if the Spec_Name doesn't exist i.e. table_2, the program should print a dash as an indicator for the user.

table_1

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| category | Spec_Name | Spec_Value   |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| Engine   |    x      | 111111111111 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| Engine   |    y      | 222222222222 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

table_2

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| category | Spec_Name | Spec_Value   |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| Engine   |    x      | 111111111111 |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

So, the Spec_Name.y wouldn't exist in table_2.

In that case, I'd like to show this for a user:

```
+---------+----------------+----------------+
|Spec_Name| car1.Spec_Value|car2.Spec_Value |
+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  x      | 111111111111   |        -       |
|  y      |      -         |    55555565    |
|  z      | 333333333333   |    77777777    |
etc.
```

Currently I loop throught my data with PHP loops like this one:

```
function printCarData($conn, $table){
  $query = "SELECT  Spec_Name, Spec_Value, SUBSTRING(Spec_Value, 1, 20), TechSpecCategoryName  FROM ".$table;
  if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
    echo"<ul>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

     if($query != $row["TechSpecCategoryName"]){

        echo "<li>"."<br>"."</li>";
      }
      echo "<li>".$row["SUBSTRING(Spec_Value, 1, 20)"]."</li>";

      $query = $row["TechSpecCategoryName"];
    } 
    echo"</ul>";
  }  
}

printCarData($link, $table_name)
```

I thought to use  `COALESCE()`, but I could not figure out, how to use it in situations as this is.

Also, I thought I could achieve this with PHP, but there are 144 Spec_Names in perfect cases, so it would be a quite long, hacky and expensive function.

Thirdly I thought, is there a way to use template tables in MySQL. So, I would have a table with all possible Spec_Names

It would be great, if anybody could point me the right direction.